# .gitignore - Ignore all files in target folder except 1 JAR file

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a maven project:

```
...
target/
|__ my-application-1.0.0-standalone.jar
```

I would like to ignore everything in the target folder except for the JAR file that matches the pattern:

```
my-application-<version>-standalone.jar
```

I need to include a specific pattern as above.

Comment: I need a specific pattern to the jar. See above edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
#Ignore everything in target folder
/target/*

#Don't ignore jar
!/target/my-application-*-standalone.jar
```

Comment: Adding the line !/path/to/my.jar AFTER the *.jar entry in .gitignore made it work for me. It does not work if the line !/path/to/my.jar appears before the *.jar line in the .gitignore file. Order is important in the .gitignore file. Burnt my hands today.